# How to test required argparse arguments during unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, argparse, python-unittest

I'm doing TDD tests for argparser. How can I test arguments with the option **required**?I need to test all options like:

- too many arguments,
- no arguments are given,
- the wrong argument is given.

I can raise SystemExit, but this is not really what I need:

```py
    def test_no_arguments(self):
        with patch.object(sys, 'exit') as mock_method:
            self.parser.parse_arguments()
            self.assertTrue(mock_method.called)
```

However, without raising system exit I have always errors like this:
[image: test_error]

### zbx-check-mount.py

```py
class CommandLine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Monitoring mounted filesystems",
                                                   formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
        self.parsed_args = None

        self.add_arguments()

    def add_arguments(self):
        """
        Add arguments to parser.
        """
        try:
            self.args_parser._action_groups.pop()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
            required = self.args_parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
            required.add_argument('--fs_name', required=True, help='Given filesystem')
        except argparse.ArgumentError as err:
            log.error('argparse.ArgumentError: %s', err)
            sys.exit(1)

    def parse_arguments(self, args=None):
        """
        Parse added arguments. Then run private method to return values
        """
        self.parsed_args = self.args_parser.parse_args()

        return self.parsed_args.fs_name,
```

### tests

```py
from pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest import TestCase
import os
import sys

try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
else:
    from mock import MagicMock, patch


sys.path.extend([os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'..','..', "bin")])
module_name = __import__('zbx-check-mount')


class TestCommandLine(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Method called to prepare the test fixture. This is called immediately before calling the test method
        """
        self.parser = module_name.CommandLine()

    def test_no_arguments(self):
        opts = self.parser.parse_arguments([])
        assert opts.fs_name

    def tearDown(self):
        """
        Method called immediately after the test method has been called and the result recorded.
        """
        pass
```

How to avoid this situation and test other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `def parse_arguments(self, args=None):`, you should pass `args` on to the parser, as in:

```
self.args_parser.parse_args(args)
```

`parse_args()` parses `sys.argv[1:]`, or if the given argument is `None`.  Otherwise it parses the provided list.

In a full distribution of `python` there's a unittest file for `argparse` (`test_argparse.py`). It's somewhat complex, defining a subclass of `ArgumentParser` that captures errors and redirects error messages.

Testing `argparse` is tricky because it looks at `sys.argv`, with the `unittest` scripts also use.  And it usually tries to exit on errors.  This has been discussed in a number of SO questions already.

Comment: It was a very useful and clear explanation! In every test I missed `self.args_parser.parse_args(args)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your symptoms correctly, you are having problems in the test harness because your monkey patched implementation of `sys.exit` actually returns, which the argparse library is not expecting.

Introducing a [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) that raises an exception, which you can then trap and verify in the unit test, may be sufficient to get around the problem.